# How libGDX render method work?

Tags: libgdx

The following are the console output of FPSLogger log() method.
I write that method in Screen render() method.
What does these mean?
FPSLogger: fps: 0
FPSLogger: fps: 61
FPSLogger: fps: 60
FPSLogger: fps: 61
FPSLogger: fps: 61
FPSLogger: fps: 61
FPSLogger: fps: 61
FPSLogger: fps: 61
FPSLogger: fps: 60

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 questions.

**How libGDX render method work?**

It is a method that is called once per every frame. It is esentially, your "game loop". There you add your games code. For example your render code.

**What does these mean?**

That number means the amount of times your render method was called in the last second.

Comment: I guess you mean "called 60 times in the last second"